# Pivot tables in pandas

Tags: python, excel

My goal is to create exactly the same functional Pivot table with python ( using `pandas` or `openpyxl`).

I have achieved some results but I would like to add the drop-down list to the table so users can filter the data.

As I understood "Rows" from the `excel` pivot is similar to Index in `pandas`, Values and columns are the same in both. But I  would like to include the filters filed from `excel` in `pandas`. Which should give me a drop-down list. How can I do this?

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(
    df2,
    index=['Sold-To Name'],
    values=['Order Qty (L)',],
    aggfunc='sum'
)
```

[image]

Comment: Not going to happen with pandas.

Comment: any other modules?